# What does this limit mean in measure theory?

Tags: real-analysis, measure-theory

Let $A$ be a subset of the real numbers.

Let $m_{\epsilon}(A)=\inf \{\sum l(A_i):A \subseteq\bigcup A_i, l(A_i) \geq \epsilon~\forall i\}$ Where each $A_i$ is an open interval and $l(A_i)$ is just the normal length for intervals.

I want to show that $\lim_{\epsilon \to 0} m_{\epsilon}(A) $ exists but I don't even really understand what this limit means.

To me I just think that if we let $\epsilon$ get as small as we like then we are just saying that each interval in the covering of $A$ can get as small as we like as we no longer need to keep the intervals length bigger than $\epsilon $.

Can anyone explain to me what such a limit means and how to prove it exists.

The only tools I have are some properties of the function $m_{\epsilon}(A)$: countable subadditivity, monotonicity and empty set gives $0$.

Comment: There is only one good book on this that I know of: B. Z. Vulikh's "Brief Course in the Theory of Functions of a Real Variable".  Give you a very nice, clean exposition.

Answer (score 1):

Monotonicity - more particularly that if $\epsilon_1 < \epsilon_2$, then $m_{\epsilon_1}(A) \le m_{\epsilon_2}(A)$ - and the fact that $m_\epsilon(A)$ is bounded below by $0$ for all $\epsilon$ is all one needs to prove that the limit exists. Note though that the limit is only one-sided, since $\epsilon > 0$ is a condition on this definition that you didn't include.

In order to explain, let me change the variable to $t$, freeing up $\epsilon$ to fill its traditional role in limits, and let $m(t) = m_t(A)$. So we are looking for $$\lim_{t \to 0+} m(t)$$ given that $0 \le m(t_1) \le m(t_2)$ whenever $0 < t_1 < t_2$

This means we want to find an $L$ so that for every $\epsilon > 0$ there is a $\delta > 0$ such that if $0 < t < \delta$ then $0 \le m(t) < \epsilon$.

Now the set $\{m(t)\mid 0 < t\}$ is bounded below by $0$, so it has an infimum $L$. For any $\epsilon > 0$, since $L$ is an infimum, there has to be a $\delta$ such that $m(\delta) < \epsilon$. If $t < \delta$ then $0 \le m(t) \le m(\delta) < m(\epsilon)$. Therefore

$$\lim_{t \to 0+} m(t) = L$$

This is a general fact about all monotone functions and one-sided limits, not just these set functions.